# Finding the "PDF Producer" or source application of a PDF

Tags: php, regex, pdf

Is there a quick-and-dirty way to access the "producer" metadata of a PDF file, using Regex or XML parsing, from a PHP application?

The technique does not have to be infallible. The objective is to prompt the user if they upload a PDF created using TeX.

Comment: Is there a known position in the file - like the first 4k - where "/Creator" will be, so this can be done by reading from a file handle? The result of calling file_get_contents() on a 200Mb+ PDF wouldn't be pretty.

Answer (score 0):

You can hack the value out by looking for the producer or creator tag but it might be encoded rather than available as ascii.

Answer (score 0):

On the command line, the following outputs a matching line:

```
 $ strings my.pdf | grep TeX


Producer (pdfTeX-1.40.10)
/Creator (TeX)
/PTEX.Fullbanner (This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 (TeX Live 2009) kpathsea    version 5.0.0)
```

You might do something similar in PHP, see [Read plain text from binary file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380330/read-plain-text-from-binary-file-with-php).